# Why doesn't my dashboard get saved?

Tags: dashboard

If I edit the dashboard widgets and save, it only lasts for the current session. Next time I log in it's the same set up as the default when I upgraded to CIVI 4.7 - i.e. Getting Started, CIVI CRM News, etc.
(Joomla 3.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this happens because the link between your Civi contact id and your CMS user has broken.  This happened to one of my clients, the cause was that I moved the Civi database & not the Drupal one, so the link was broken. The table to look at in Civi is civicrm_uf_match - field is uf_id which should link to your CMS user table (in my case, it was Drupal's 'users' table)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andy. Seems that it is indeed a broken link between the user id in CIVI and the Joomla user id. That said, I'm not quite sure how to fix it.
Editing the table in php MyAdmin doesn't work, I get the error, 
"MySQL said: Documentation
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`[database_name]`.`civicrm_uf_match`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_uf_match_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) "

Comment: The field uid in Drupal table 'users' matches to the field 'uf_id' in the Cibi table civicrm_uf_match.  Of course, you're using Joomla but I would try changing the appropriate Joomla table to match the Civi table.
If you think this is the correct answer could you kindly indicate that it is to keep the stack system going?  thanks.

Comment: @johnnybgoodwin The foreign key constraint failure suggests maybe you're using the wrong ID.  The "foreign key constraint" prevents you from changing the `contact_id` to one that doesn't exist in `civicrm_contact`.  Maybe you're conflating the `contact_id` with the `uf_id`?